# Random divisable at least one of two integers in c#

Tags: c#, random

I've got an integer that I'd like to assign a value to by using Random.
The randomly chosen number must be divisable by 2 or 5 (or both).
For divisable only by two I would just multiply the Random result * 2, but it's not an option here.

How to do this?

edit:
I came up with this code, it's probably very inefficient though:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] tab = new int[5];
            Random random = new Random();
            int i = 0;
            while (i < tab.Length)
            {
                int tempInteger = random.Next(101);
                if (tempInteger % 2 == 0 || tempInteger % 5 == 0)
                {
                    tab[i] = tempInteger;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why is multiplying by 2 not an option? Some even numbers are also divisible by 5, so you haven't really described the problem.

Comment: I mean that by multiplying random integer by 2 I would get even integers not divisable by 5. Multiplying by 2 and 5 would mean I would lose integers divisable by 2, but not by 10 (like 16 and 18).

Comment: You need to specify the distribution that you want. Different generation schemes have different probabilities for the 2 divisibility properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not explicitly meantioned in the question but I would expect a behavior where each result number is generated with same probability. The solution suggested by @RodrickChapman works well but for example number 10 will appear in the result twice more often than number 6. It's due to the fact, that 10 can be generated as `2*5` and also as `5*2` but number 6 can be only generated as `2*3`

First let's make simple observation: each result number must end with number 0, 2, 4, 5, 6 or 8. All we need to do is to randomly choose from these numbers and add this number to some random number which ends with 0 (0, 10, 20, 40, ....).

```
int upperBound = 100;
var random = new Random();
var choices = new[] { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8 };
var baseNumber = random.Next(0, upperBound / 10) * 10; 
var lastDigit = choices[random.Next(choices.Length)];
var result = baseNumber + lastDigit;
```

Answer (score 3):

What about something like:

```
void Main()
{
    var xs = new[] { 2, 5 };
    var rand = new Random();

    var r = xs[rand.Next(0, xs.Length)] * rand.Next(SOME_UPPER_BOUND);
}
```

The idea is that we first choose either 2 or 5, then multiply that choice by an arbitrary number between 0 and `SOME_UPPER_BOUND`.

I tested it with `SOME_UPPER_BOUND = 101`, and empirically `r` is either divisible by 2, 5, or 10.

If you want *equal* probabilities of divisibility by either 2, 5, or both (i.e. 10), then change the first line to `var xs = new[] {2, 5, 10}`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could always multiply it by 10 - that way it will always be divisible by 2 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, I would create **two** random numbers like this. One is the **base** one, another one ranges from 0 to 2, which will be mapped to multiply of 2, 5, and 10 respectively, and then multiply the two of them such as this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int baseInt = rand.Next(101);
int choiceInt = rand.Next(0, 3);
List<int> mapInts = new List<int>() { 2, 5, 10 };
int finalInt = baseInt * mapInts[choiceInt];
```

the `finalInt` would always be divisible by 2, 5 or 10.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to multiply random generated number to 2 or 5.

Or you can generate array of number which is divisible and randomly select them from array by randomly generated index.